# In what instance would git cherry-pick be needed instead of git merge?

Tags: git

For moving an individual from one branch to another I realize that there are a few options in git. I have experimented with `git merge` and `git cherry-pick` but am failing to see when `git cherry-pick` is preferable.

My understanding is the following:

`git merge <hash>` moves the specified commit from one branch to the other preserving it as one commit.

`git cherry-pick <hash>` creates a copy of the commit in the second branch but it is separate with its own commit hash.

The first option seems preferable to me but what are the instances when `cherry-pick` would be preferred?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you have a branch from `master` that has a bunch of commits. Maybe you made a change that is appropriate on `master`, but you don't want to bring in *all* of the changes (a small bug fix, for example, or the addition of a small feature). With `git cherry-pick`, you can grab *only that commit* from the other branch and bring it into `master`.

Comment: if you merge *specifying* the hash, does it only merge that one commit?

Comment: @hvgotcodes: No, when you merge, you get `<hash>` and all of the ancestors in `<hash>` since it diverged from the branch you're merging into. A branch name is really only a named hash.

Comment: I was under the impression when you specified a hash (`git merge <hash>`) you were only getting that one commit. This is incorrect?

Comment: @markdorison: Yes. If you specify a hash, you get all the ancestors of that hash.

Answer (score 0):

Another use case is when you lose a commit and want to get it back.
http://www.programblings.com/2008/06/07/the-illustrated-guide-to-recovering-lost-commits-with-git/

> mathieu@ml recovery (master)$ git cherry-pick
>   93b0c51cfea8c731aa385109b8e99d19b38a55be Finished one cherry-pick.
>   Created commit f443703: Now that was cool  1 files changed, 1
>   insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)  create mode 100644 cool_file

You  need to have the hash of course.